# Get custom label from clicked column of MS Chart control (WinForm)

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, mschart

I'm using `MS Chart` control in my WinForm project:
[image]

I want write some code to get clicked column's label, e.g if user clicked A column it returns "A [ EAF/LF ]" and if user clicks B column it returns "B [ VD/VOD ]".
So I wrote following code to find clicked column in chart and show the custom defined label:

```
private void chart_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var result = chart.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);

    if (result.ChartElementType == ChartElementType.DataPoint)
    {
       var selectedColumn = chart.Series[0].Points[result.PointIndex];
       var customLabel = selectedColumn.AxisLabel + "[ "
                         result.Axis.CustomLabels[result.PointIndex] + " ]";
       // other codes
     }
}
```

But when run the code the `result.Axis` is `null`. Does anyone know where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Axis` property has value only if the object returned by the `HitTest` is associated with an axis. For example, a tick mark or stripline. For the `DataPoint` object it returns `null`.

To get the `CustomLabels` you could use the below code.

```
chart.ChartAreas[chart.Series[0].CharArea].AxisX.CustomLabels[result.PointIndex];
```